# Solving a non linear ODE problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please I will like to solve this non linear ODE problem

$$
y'(x) = e^{-b(x)} \times \left( p + \left( \frac{q}{n} y(x) \right)\right)\left( n - y(x) \right). 
$$

Can anyone help? Thank you

I made some correction to the equation

Comment: What is the motivation? It can be done, I believe, without too much trouble. I am typing something now.

Comment: It is pretty similar to the logistical equation, isn't it?

Comment: It is part of the equations I am using for an optimization problem with regards to information propagation. Thank you for the help

Comment: Hmm... well, the answer I have typed up was for the old equation, I'm afraid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same approach as izoec, we can arrive to$$\frac{n (n (p+q) \log (n p+q y)-q y)}{q^2}= \int e^{-b(x)} \, \mathrm{d} x = \xi (x)$$ and the solution of $y$ is $$y=- \frac {n} {q} \left(p+(p+q) W\left(-\frac{\left(e^{\frac{\xi(x)  q^2}{n^2
   p}-1}\right)^{\frac{p}{p+q}}}{n (p+q)}\right)\right)$$

I hope and wish that I did not make any mistake.

Comment: Please what is your definition of $W$ in your solution. I do not really understand. Please clarify thank you

Comment: $W$ is Lambert function.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Answer addresses the problem prior to a recent edit that changed the equation of the question.

From 
$$
y'(x) = \left( p + \frac{q}{n} \right) y(x)(n - y(x))*e^{-b(x)}
$$
we can solve it by putting it in the form

$$
\int \frac{y'(x)}{y(x)(n - y(x))} \, \mathrm{d} x = \left( p + \frac{q}{n} \right) \int e^{-b(x)} \, \mathrm{d} x = \xi (x)
$$

and as the integral on the left becomes

$$
\int \frac{y'(x)}{y(x)(n - y(x))} \, \mathrm{d} x = \frac{1}{n} \int y'(x) \cdot \left( \frac{1}{y(x)} + \frac{1}{n - y(x)} \right) \, \mathrm{d} x = \frac{1}{n} \ln \left| \frac{y(x)}{n - y(x)}  \right|,
$$

then we have that $y(x)$ satisfies
$$
\frac{1}{n} \ln \left| \frac{y(x)}{n - y(x)} \right| = \xi(x) + C
$$
and 
$$
y(x) = (n - y(x)) Ae^{n \xi(x)} \implies y(x) = \frac{nA e^{n \xi(x)}}{1 + Ae^{n \xi(x)}}.
$$
[$A$ of course is simply $e^{nC}$.]